# column "foo" is of type test12.test_type[] but expression is of type record[]

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to create a composite TYPE in Greenplum and using that an array of that TYPE. But when I try to insert data into table, it always says

> column "foo" is of type test11.test_type[] but expression is of type record[]. 
>   HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
>   SQL state: 42804".

I have tried all the ways of inserting an array into greenplum. for eg. `array[(3,4),(2,4)] and '{(1,3), (1,2)}'`

```
create type test11.test123 as (a1 int, a2 int);

create table test11.test(faa qlake_streaming_ioc.test11[], aa int);

insert into test(faa, aa) values (array[(3,4),(2,4)] , 3);
```

Comment: I don't know greenplum, but in Postgres you would use `array[(3,4),(2,4)]::test123[]`

Comment: thanks that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say if that works on Greenplum, but you can try:

```
INSERT INTO tab (foo)
   VALUES (ARRAY[(3,4), (2,4)]::test11.test_type[]);
```